# Removing the gray border/rectangle in Visual studio 2012/2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, color-scheme

I've changed the colors in Visual studio 2015 so that when I highlight a word , it colors declarations in yellow and references in green.

But for some reason - there is a gray border around the declarative part :

[image]

*Question*

Is there any way to remove the gray border ?

Edit

It seems that it happend also in earlier versions in another place  - "Highlight current line" :

[Here is the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262411/how-to-change-border-width-and-color-of-highlight-current-line-in-visual-studi) But I can't find the exact color setting to change (my question is not about current line but highlight reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to change the Item Foreground colour of the **Highlighted Definition** entry to match your default background colour and it will disappear.