# what is the property called when clicking a line in editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, themes

since yesterday I m trying to change the border color when clicking a line in the text-editor
I cant find this property. its really annoying..
here is a gif how its currently looks.
`
I dont want this white border. please anyone can help

Comment: Asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262411/how-to-change-border-width-and-color-of-highlight-current-line-in-visual-studi#:~:text=Go%20to%20Tools%20%3E%20Options%20%3E%20Environment,by%20link%20and%20cite%20above.&text=In%20order%20to%20change%20border,foreground%22%20for%20both%20of%20them.

Comment: @Luuk answer helped. me I cant mark it as resolved. thanx anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your language, the path should be something like this:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Highlight current line
```

You have to uncheck the box :)

Comment: `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Highlight Current Line`     setting things back to 'Default' seems to be a more correct solution.

Comment: thx for answer. this would disable  it. but is there a way to change the color?

Comment: Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors

Comment: @Luuk this property is default. but the border is still white? the creator of the theme just show it for visual studio code. https://github.com/gjactat/visual-studio-2017-palenight-theme/issues/1

Comment: thats in visual studio Code `editor.linehighlightborder` where can I find this in visual studio

Comment: @Mariestorch: see my reply to your question. If that still 'does not work' try hitting the `Use Defaults` button.

Comment: Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > 
Select Text Editor option from  Show settings for dropdown 
> select Highlight Current Line option from Display Item 
>select forgroud and backgroud colour